# what are datatypes supported by FACT ++?

Tags: owl, ontology, reasoning, protege4, fact++

I am working in Ontology but when I used FACT++ in Protege , FACT++ throws me an error. I have reading about the datatypes error with FACT++ but I can´t found the datatypes supported by FACT++.

I am reading in http://owl.cs.manchester.ac.uk/tools/fact/ and de MAiling lists of Protege.

Comment: Which version of FaCT++ and what error exactly do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FaCT++ is meant to support all datatypes specified in the OWL 2 DL specs, however older versions had incomplete support. So it's important to know which version you're working with.

Comment: I am working with FACT plusplus plugin 1.6.4 and this plugin does not work with datatype unsignedInt in protege 5.0.o Build 1

Comment: Looks like that's still not supported. I'll file an issue.

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/dtsarkov/factplusplus/issues/64/datatype-support-unsignedint